# Pandas select match multiple columns

Tags: pandas, multi-index

I have data like this:

```
category = ['Car','Car','Car','Car','Truck','Truck','Truck']
name = ['Camry','Camry','Camry','Camry','Tacoma','Tundra','Tundra']
year = ['2007','2007','2008','2009','2010','2010','2011']
vals = [0.1,0.5,0.2,0.9,0.8,0.4,0.9]
df = pd.DataFrame({'Category': category,
                   'Name': name,
                   'Year': year,
                   'Vals': vals})
```

| index | Category | Name | Year | Vals |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Car | Camry | 2007 | 0.1 |
| 1 | Car | Camry | 2007 | 0.5 |
| 2 | Car | Camry | 2008 | 0.2 |
| 3 | Car | Camry | 2009 | 0.9 |
| 4 | Truck | Tacoma | 2010 | 0.8 |
| 5 | Truck | Tundra | 2010 | 0.4 |
| 6 | Truck | Tundra | 2011 | 0.9 |

I then have a set of combinations of (Category, Name, Year) that I want to filter the data frame for. They could be in whatever format, but here they are in a data frame.

```
combinations_i_want = pd.DataFrame()
# (Car, Camry, 2007)
combinations_i_want = combinations_i_want.append({'Category':'Car', 'Name':'Camry','Year':'2007'},ignore_index=True) # 2 matches in df
# (Truck, Tundra, 2010)
combinations_i_want = combinations_i_want.append({'Category':'Truck', 'Name':'Tundra','Year':'2010'},ignore_index=True) # 1 match in df
```

I want to extract the rows in df that exactly match these two combinations. Those would be rows 0, 1, and 5. The resulting table would look like this:

| index | Category | Name | Year | Vals |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Car | Camry | 2007 | 0.1 |
| 1 | Car | Camry | 2007 | 0.5 |
| 5 | Truck | Tundra | 2010 | 0.4 |

Note: I don't need to old indices, they are just for help visualizing.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply right join on the columns you want.

```
result = df.merge(combinations_i_want, how='right', on=['Category', 'Name', 'Year'])
```

Answer (score 2):

use dataframe query it will give you a perfect match based on boolean logic

```
print(df.query("(Category=='Car' and Name=='Camry' and Year=='2007') or (Category=='Truck' and Name=='Tundra' and Year=='2010')"))
```

output:

```
     Category    Name  Year  Vals
   0      Car   Camry  2007   0.1
   1      Car   Camry  2007   0.5
   5    Truck  Tundra  2010   0.4
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `.loc` and `.isin` instead of `.append`

Your sentence could be something like:

```
df.loc[(df['Category'].isin(['Car', 'Truck'])) & (df['Name'].isin(['Camry', 'Tundra'])) & (df['Year'].isin(['2007', '2010']))]
```

That should yield the results you're expecting.

You can assign it to a variable if you want such as

```
combinations_i_want = df.loc[(df['Category'].isin(['Car', 'Truck'])) &
         (df['Name'].isin(['Camry', 'Tundra'])) &
         (df['Year'].isin(['2007', '2010']))]
    
print(combinations_i_want)
```

Comment: In my real data, there could be a hypothetical (Car, Tundra, 2010) meaning I need each column to match up perfectly.

Comment: I believe OP meant they want the rows that match exactly a row of combination that they specified before which is basically a sql join.

Comment: @rdk then you could use the ```|``` instead of ```&``` leaving the option open to be one or the other.